# Setting Django environment variables for specific Pycharm project

Tags: python, django, pycharm, development-environment

I have multiple Django Pycharm projects, each with a different `DATABASE_URL` and `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` Windows environment variable.

Is there a way to set these variables specifically for individual projects so I can switch back and forth with ease? Also: in a way that makes them available in the terminal?

I've read suggestions for setting them in the project's virtual environment or with the *Run/Debug Configurations* panel in Pycharm, but in neither case have I been able to get things to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Run/Debug Configurations of Pycharm.

Go to the toolbar then "Run" menu then "Edit configurations" option, create a new configuration or edit an existing one then you will find "enviroment" section here you can add your env variables in the "Enviroment variables" field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How would this work in a typical Django development workflow? Under 'Script' would I put the `manage.py` file? I don't think this would apply when I run `py manage.py runserver` or `py manage.py shell_plus` in the terminal.

Comment: Go to the toolbar then 'Run' menu then 'Run' or 'Debug' option and select your configuration.

Comment: Under _Run/Debug Configurations_, I don't have the _Django Server_ configuration template, nor is a plugin with that name available in the plugin marketplace. It looks like this is only available in the Professional edition of PyCharm?